# F# assigning values to arrays in a for loop

Tags: arrays, variables, f#

All im trying to do is assign the dice vlaues into the array but the values just dont change

```
let diceRoll () =
    let random = new System.Random()
    for i = 0 to 4 do
        let r = random.Next(1,6)
        let b = r
        printf " Dice %u = %i |" i r
        let diceValue = [|1;2;3;4;5|]
        let assign = diceValue.[i] = r 
        printfn "%u" assign
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operator for assingment in F# is `<-` rather than `=`.

In your code you have:

```
let assign = diceValue.[i] = r
```

This is an equality test and it checks whether the value `diceValue.[i]` is equal to `r`. The result is a Boolean value that you assing to the variable `assign`.

If you want to mutate the array, you can do this using:

```
diceValue.[i] <- r
```

I'm not exactly sure what you are expecting to do with the `assign` variable. The assignment operation returns `unit`, which is a bit like `void` in other languages, so you do not get any useful result.

If you want to mutate all values in the array, then you will also need to define the array outside of the loop:

```
let random = new System.Random()
let diceValue = [|1;2;3;4;5|]
for i = 0 to 4 do
    let r = random.Next(1,6)
    diceValue.[i] <- r
```

And as a side-note, this can be done more nicely using the `Array.init` function, which initializes an array and calls the provided function to get a value for each of the elements of the array:

```
let diceValue = Array.init 5 (fun _ ->
  random.Next(1,6))
```

Comment: Do you know how i would be able to then count the occurances of 1-6?

Comment: @Julian That's better asked as a new question - that way, you can describe your current approach and people can help with a specific question about it.